# How to escape path names returned by a PowerShell provider

Tags: c#, powershell, path, escaping

I'm writing a PowerShell provider written in C#. The provider exposes a tree of objects, whose names are arbitrary unicode strings that can include characters like `"`, `'`, and so on.

I'm trying to understand how to properly return these names, but have not been able to find any documentation for how to do so.

1. How are PowerShell paths escaped and displayed?
2. Are there length restrictions on paths or segments of a path?
3. Is there a grammar or regular expression to validate PowerShell paths or segments of a path?
4. Is it legal for two items to have the same name (and hence the same path)? This is the case in my scenario, where names are not required to be unique. (There are unique properties e.g., an ID, but the names are not unique.)

Comment: Just in case the docs are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126186(v=vs.85).aspx)  

1) Hopefully, Path escaping would just be about how you input the string.  If it is not, I think you would have to handle this in your provider.

2) I don't think the provider framework limits the path explicitly.

4) Your provider would have to understand how to handle this.  How would you handle get-item, when there are two items?

Comment: @TravisPlunk, about 4) since they are objects they can be held and filtered programmatically. They do have uniqueness, but the uniqueness is not simply in the name. As an example, many emails can have the same title, but different underlying unique ids. The email title seems to map naturally to the PowerShell name. I just want to be sure that this is the accepted thing to do in PowerShell.

Comment: @TravisPlunk, consider rewriting your comment as an answer. About 1) I did not find any information on escaping path separators in the link you provided. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

let's look at an example in the file system:

`` PS> dir foo*
    Directory: C:\Users\jimtru\AppData\Local\Temp
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/1/2016  11:11 AM             11 foo[bar].'baz'
-a----         6/1/2016  11:13 AM              8 foo[bar].`baz` ``

the first thing to notice is there are quotes (single and back) which are rendered simply, no additional characters indicating escapement in the output, however, these might cause PowerShell a bit of heartburn if you just try to get their contents:

`` PS> get-content foo[bar].'baz'
get-content : An object at the specified path foo[bar].baz...
PS> get-content foo[bar].`baz`...
get-content : An object at the specified path foo[bar]az` ``

there are a couple of ways around this. We provide `-LiteralPath` for some cmdlets:

`PS> get-content -LiteralPath "foo[bar].'baz'"
sdflkj`

notice that I have included double-quotes around the string. This is because the single quotes would get treated as a string element, so `'foo'` would be replaced by `foo`, the double quotes indicate that the parser should look at the entire string (double-quote-to-double-quote). Another way to proceed is to use the escape character (back-quote).

`` PS> get-content 'foo`[bar`].`baz`'
sdflkj ``

As for paths which are identical, I would suggest that you avoid that. You need some way to disambiguate one entity from another. You should be sure that the path that you create is unique to your resource. Remember that you construct this path in your provider, so you can add the disambiguating features as part of your provider.

Lastly, there are limitations on length which can be expressed as a path *on the filesystem*. AFIK, there are no limitations on non-path "paths"

Comment: thanks. What about path separators, i.e. / or \, in the path? The original post is about arbitrary unicode paths, so need to know the set of characters that should be treated specially by either the provider, cmdlets, or scripts.